# "Wi-Fi" process in OSX El Capitan uses a lot of CPU

Tags: wifi, macos, cpu

"Wi-Fi" process takes a lot of CPU almost all the time. Why is it happening, and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstallation of OSX El Capitan helped. Don't know why it was happening.

Comment: I reinstall it and no change, 80-90% CPU used by Wi-Fi and also a lot of faults. Did you anything else?

Comment: I'm adding a +1 since you came back and answered. There's always time to edit or get more answers/change the checkmark if more details arrive. Thanks and don't worry about one internet negative vote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have this problem in High Sierra, and am able to mitigate it by killing the process in the activity monitor (it does not affect my wi-fi connection). I do not know why it happens.